# How to return inserted row from INSERT statement with php, SQL SERVER 2005?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the *easiest / most efficient* way to get the **entire** row inserted after an INSERT statement?

I am pretty sure I could do this as follows:

```
$aQuery = "INSERT into myTable (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 'Hello', 'Goodbye')";
//the IDENTITY coloumn in myTable is named id
$result = sqlsrv_query($myConn, $aQuery );
if ($result) {
    $res = sqlsrv_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res);
    $lastInsertId = $row[0];
    $subQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable where id = {$lastInsertId}";
    $subResult = sqlsrv_query($myConn, $subQuery);
    if ($subResult) {
        while($subrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($subResult)) {
            echo($subrow ['id'] . ', '.
                 $subrow ['a'] . ', '.
                 $subrow ['b']);  //etc...
        }
     }
}
```

However, I am concerned about the possibility of **another** insert occurring just before my `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and thus messing up my logic to boot. How can I be certain that the last inserted id is truly the INSERT I called previously, and not something happening somewhere else?

Is there a more appropriate way of doing this, perhaps a complete SQL solution (such that the query returns the row automatically rather than using PHP)?

UPDATE: myTable **DOES** have an explicitly defined (and auto-incremented) identity column, named `id`.

Comment: Your concern is very unrealistic.

Comment: And yet is happens every day due to poor design. If you have 1 person using the system it will never happen. But when you have 100 people using same system at the same time, suddenly odds increase drastically. OP is correct making it a concern and thinking ahead.

Comment: @Andrey - My thoughts exactly. Thanks for the backup.

Comment: @stevether they are NOT unrealistic, all the contrary. I was supporting a system with just a few users (about 40) and just because @@identity was being used many times wrong records ended up being updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
"INSERT into myTable (a, b, c) OUTPUT Inserted.a, Inserted.b, Inserted.c VALUES (1, 'Hello', 'Goodbye')
```

Comment: How did you send a message to my inbox, yet there is no comment here from you?

Comment: Oh, duh. I thought maybe there was a feature I was missing.

Comment: One challenge I have was then after I insert it, how do I get the results of the insert? That is where I am stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server, you would use select `@lastID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

And `@LastID` will have the last id inserted for the current scope; therefore, if there was another insertion in the middle, you would still get the correct record on your select.

Never use `@@Identity` for this or you may end up in a situation like you described.

Comment: Will this work if the field is not identity? I do not think OP is using the idenity field.

Comment: @Andrey Excellent point. No, I doubt it will work, but if the OP is not using an identity field, he should probably run and add one ;)

Comment: Well we do not know what and how he is using ID. He may not want it to be incremental by 1.

Comment: Than your insert statement should be VALUES ('Hello', 'Goodbye')

Comment: @Andrey, it doesn't matter if it is incremental or not. As long as it is the PK and it is an integer I believe SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return it. One can generate the IDs if that's what one wants (in fact, manually generated ids are used in enterprise environments to facilitate replication). However, your point is still valid in the sense that the PK may not be an integer at all. It may very well be a GUID or what have you and I don't think SCOPE_IDENTITY will work in that scenario. I have to test to confirm the behavior but will be later tonight because I'm outta here now.

Comment: @Andrey +1 for pointing out my broad assumption and also pointing out to LittleTreex that he shouldn't specify the ID column on his insert statement since he confirmed that it is an auto-generated integer.

Comment: @Icarus According to the documentation, in order to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() the field has to be identity. The link to the doc is in my answer. They do not say anything about nonidentity fields.

Comment: @Andry & Icarus - I didn't specify my id (in the insert statement) at all, note the column is a, where below I clearly use: where id = blah. In this example, my id column is assumed to be named id. Sorry for the confusion there, but I will edit my question for more clarity.

Comment: @Andrey I see what you mean. If that's the case then it sucks, because I can't think of a reason for an identify column not being the same as any other integer as long as the other integer is a PK. What difference does it make if it is sequential or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use identity field (which maybe you should) there is a command called SCOPE_IDENTIY() which info you can find here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Since you do not use it, you do not have to select latest data since you have it when you insert, so just use same data instead of selecting.